# ROS_NAMESPACE , tf , turtlebot_bringup and turtlebot_navigation

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I'm looking to provide a namespace for my turtlebot.
In my .bashrc file, I've set:
`export TURTLEBOT_NAME=Dave` and
`export ROS_NAMESPACE=$TURTLEBOT_NAME`

After launching `turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch` and `turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch` the list of topics are all in the `/Dave` namespace, however the following:  `/dave/incompatible_rapp_list /dave/rapp_list /dave/status /diagnostics /diagnostics_agg /diagnostics_toplevel_state /rosout /rosout_agg /scan /tf /tf_static` are not or have incorrect namespace. `dave` not `Dave`. More importantly I'm looking to solve the `tf` and `tf_static` because those are very important for actual navigation. I was looking at [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/?answer=41434#post-id-41434) ROS Answers but couldn't solve my problem.

Any thoughts?
Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264555/ros_namespace-,-tf-,-turtlebot_bringup-and-turtlebot_navigation/) by [j_salfity](https://answers.ros.org/users/27623/j_salfity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-23**:
Not sure whether this is your issue, but: by convention the use of uppercase names is typically discouraged (it is allowed though, see [wiki/Naming](http://wiki.ros.org/Names)). It could be that some nodes are (incorrectly) lowercasing any names they receive, resulting in the `Dave`->`dave` problem.

**Comment by [j_salfity](https://answers.ros.org/users/27623/j_salfity/) on 2017-06-23**:
Got it, thanks. Any thoughts on the `tf` and `tf_static` frames naming?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-23**:
Take a look at [Simulating Multiple Husky UGVs in Gazebo](https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/2016/03/simulating-multiple-husky-ugvs-in-gazebo/) on the clearpath blog. That is specifically about running two instances of Husky at the same time in Gazebo, but probably deals with the same issue(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wrong all along, `tf` and `tf_static` need to be in their own namespace.

---

Originally posted by [j_salfity](https://answers.ros.org/users/27623/j_salfity/) with karma: 16 on 2017-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-27**:
If this answers your question then you should mark it as the correct answer.